# Как подключить .htaccess на reg.ru?

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

У меня хостинг и домен лежат на reg.ru . Я знаю, как работать с .htaccess , но никак не пойму, как его туда подключить. Я кидаю правильно написанный .htaccess в главную директорию сайта, но он не работает. Как это решить?
Может, есть какой-то другой способ оформить редирект? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Убедитесь, что права на файл .htaccess выставлены правильно. Должно быть 644, ну или как более безопасный вариант - 444.
Второе: нет никакой гарантии, что ваш файл (гадать по кофейной гуще?) работоспособен, и все директивы верны. Может у вас неверно там указаны какие-нибудь редиректы, к примеру, а вы пишете, что виноват reg.ru.